# Confusion for Proof of GCD Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, euclidean-algorithm

I'm having some trouble understanding a part of a theorem that states that the gcd between two integers exists and is unique. First it state the Euclidean Algorithm for positive integers, that for positive integers $a$ and $b$,
$$
\begin{align}
a & = bq_1 + r_1 \\
b & = r_1q_2 + r_2 \\
r_1 & = r_2q_3 + r_3
\end{align}
$$
As long as the remainders aren't zero

And so on and so forth. Then it states the fact that 
$b > r_1 > r_2 > r_3 >\cdots>0$

Then it says, using induction, that 
$$0 \le r_i \le b - i.$$

Where did that $b - i$ come from? What does it mean? How is this inequality true?

Answer (score 3):

$r_1<b$, since $r_1$ is the remainder upon dividing by $b$. Thus $r_1\le b-1$, since we are dealing with integers here. Next, $r_{k+1}<r_k$, and hence $r_{k+1}\le r_k-1$ for the same reason. From this, the conclusion is immediate by induction.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I didn't realize that for integers, if a < b implies a <= b - 1. Mind blown haha